# Wrapping query to get a count greater than 3

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT ownerid, zip, vin, make, model FROM listing 
WHERE (ownerid, upper(make)) 
IN (SELECT dealership, attribute FROM ownerproduct WHERE productid = 'FRONT_LISTING')
AND new = 'Y'
ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM;
```

My query produces a front_listing. As it stands now, it only produces it about 85% percent of the time, so I need to wrap my query to get a count of ownerid, make, model to be greater than 3, in order for my query results to produce a front_listing 100% of the time.

---

Edit:

So I need a query where they have at least more than 3 models associated with the ownerid and make. So, for example, an owner id might have a model amount that is less than 3 however that same model might have a different ownerid where it does have a count more than 3 thus why I need a count/amount of ownerid, make and model to be greater than 3.

Comment: I added the Oracle table because the syntax and functions look like Oracle.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  You want to only include rows from `listing` if they are for an ownerid, make, and model that have at least three (3) VINs?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak I have edited my question.

Comment: Why the downvote guys?

Comment: People like to see some kinda of attempt might be the reason for downvotes,I didnt downvote you.

Comment: @Mihai What a shame. People are too downvote happy on this site.

Comment: I generally only see downvotes on questions that are problematic in some way; eg. not enough information to describe the issue to those of us who can't see your database. Is that not a fair reason to downvote in your opinion?

Comment: @Boneist There is nothing wrong in downvoting however it is really rude to downvote and not tell the OP why you chose to downvote. At least tell the OP why you downvoted so that they can fix their mistake.

Comment: @Robben true; I generally leave a comment if I downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
SELECT ownerid, zip, vin, make, model 
FROM 
(
SELECT ownerid, zip, vin, make, model, count(*) over (partition by ownerid, make, model) cnt FROM listing 
WHERE (ownerid, upper(make)) 
IN (SELECT dealership, attribute FROM ownerproduct WHERE productid = 'FRONT_LISTING')
AND new = 'Y'
)
WHERE cnt > 3
ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM );
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like your query is working. Did my question make more sense after the edit or should I clarify a bit more?

Comment: You can edit it if you want.  I was sort of guessing as your intention... :)  I think the confusion part was why this extra condition would make your query return data more often.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how efficient your query would be with this sort of `WHERE` clause:

```
 WHERE (ownerid, upper(make)) 
    IN (SELECT dealership, attribute FROM ownerproduct WHERE productid = 'FRONT_LISTING')
```

I would try something like this instead:

```
SELECT ownerid, zip, vin, make, model FROM (
    SELECT op.dealership AS ownerid, l.zip, l.vin, l.make, l.model
         , COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY op.dealership, l.make, l.model) cnt
      FROM ownerproduct op INNER JOIN listing l
        ON op.dealership = l.ownerid
       AND op.attribute = UPPER(l.make)
     WHERE op.productid = 'FRONT_LISTING'
       AND l.new = 'Y'
) WHERE cnt >= 3
 ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE;
```

P.S. The reason I used `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE` instead of `DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM` is that the latter is deprecated (since 11gR1).